# Transfer files from device to pc using sockets over USB

Tags: android, sockets, usb

I am able to transfer files from my android device to pc over WiFi network but not able to figure-out how to transfer files over USB using sockets (Followed this post : [connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb](http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/)). Has anyone ever tried it before and is it possible...if so please help me on the same.

Comment: USB has no sockets. It's just a serial hardware connection standard which is used with several protocols on top. Like [mass storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class), [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) and whatever protocol `adb` is using. You can't simply open sockets to the PC because that would require both the PC and the device to have support for such a protocol in their USB drivers.

Comment: @zapl thanks for your immediate reply but can you please have a look at this post (http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/) because they say that its possible through port forwarding.

Comment: Yes, what they do is to use `adb` (and it's protocol). That requires that a program on the PC tells the installed `adb` software that it should forward a certain TCP port on the PC to the device + an app that listens on that port. In that case you can use a socket between that PC program and your app. But it's not working without that program and it requires to have `adb` installed on the PC.

Comment: @zapl I followed the instructions on that post and even was able to establish connection but still not able to transfer files. Do you know of any such example that can do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. USB connection has no sockets. You can't also make IP connection over USB cable. Of course you can write your own firmware and device driver for PC.